# Newtonian time in relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Someone asked me about how the time it takes for an event to occur might not be invariant in the context of special relativity, and the response I provided was as follows:

> In special relativity, Newtonian time $t$ isn't invariant under Lorentz transformations. To illustrate this, suppose that you perform a measurement that quantifies the time during which a higher density object sinks in the bottom of the container. Then, compared to an observer that is at rest with the fluid, the density of the fluid is higher, and greater buoyant force is exerted on the object so that it will take *longer* time to sink in, with respect to an observer that is co-moving with the object.

Admittedly, I am not sure whether I provided a reasonable thought experiment. Can I hear your feedback?

Comment: If you have a balloon under water, will the Lorentz contraction cause it to take longer to float?

Comment: I would say this is very contrived reasoning. A duration is the difference between two readings of the clock in the local reference system. What triggers those readings is entirely irrelevant. It's also not like we are actually seeing a squeezed container if we are looking at one that moves fast relative to us. What we would see is a rotated container with a slight distortion. See Terrel rotation. So your explanation is that the density changes, even though what an observer "sees" looks like the same volume and the rest mass doesn't change, either.

Comment: Time as a parameter is nowhere invariant. Duration is the interesting quantity.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you mean the first observer is at rest with the water and he sees the sinking object only moving vertically. The second observer sees the water and the object comoving horizontally?

Comment: It would be more helpful to your friend if you let them know that you don't know much about relativity, and suggest some good websites or books for them.

Comment: Why don't you just respond: "I don't know." It is OK to not know. It is OK to admit that you do not know.

Comment: My most sincere apologies for that, you are right. I acted too quickly when they asked, and I should have taken time to first know if I understand it precisely myself. But as a positive thing, I will pick up a book and start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpret your question is this:

> Observer 1) There is a well filled with water and a high density
> object takes time t to fall from top to bottom as measured by this
> observer at rest with the water.
>
> Observer 2) The time t' taken for the object to fall from top to
> bottom according to an observer comoving vertically with the sinking
> object, will be longer because he will measure the density of the
> water to be greater than measured by observer 1 and the greater
> buoyancy will slow the object down in the point of view of this
> comoving observer.
>
> There is no horizontal motion.

The main problem is that where there is buoyancy or 'falling' there has to be acceleration or gravity and things get complicated quickly. For instant in a gravity situation, the clock at the top of the well will be ticking faster than a clock at the bottom.

To make an initial analysis, lets assume the gravitational acceleration is small and the relativistic effects of the gravity is negligible compared to the vertical velocity. We can now assume the two clocks at the top and bottom of the well that observer 1 is using for his calculations, are running at (effectively/almost) the same rate, so as an approximation, we can use the Lorentz transformation:

$t' = (t - vx)/\sqrt{(1-v^2)}$

where x is the height of the well and using units such that the speed of light is one.

Lets says according to observer 1, the well is $x = 8$ ls deep, the vertical velocity is $v = 0.8c$ and time $t = 10$ seconds.

The time t' measured by observer 2 is then:

$t' = (10 - 0.8 * 8) / \sqrt{(1-0.8^2)} = 6$ seconds.

You can see the first problem. The time measured by the comoving observer 2 is less than the time measured by observer 1 so the comoving observer see things falling faster. This is partly because observer 2 sees the height of the well to be length contracted.

In special relativity, forces parallel to the motion have the same value in both the frame where the object is stationary and in the frame where the object is moving. This means whatever observer 1 measures the buoyancy to be, observer will measure the same buoyancy force. We cannot attribute any difference in time to differences in observed buoyancy forces.

An additional complication is friction but we will assume a frictionless fluid.

A further complication that cannot be ignored is that to observer 2, the water is coming up towards him at high velocity and the impact force of the water hitting the bottom of the object and imparting momentum will create a significant opposing upward force. The problem as before, is that whatever vertical parallel forces that observer 2 measures will also be measured to be the same as measured by observer 1.

Overall, I would say there is too much going on in the your scenario for anyone to give an exact answer (not impossible but not trivial) making it difficult to claim it is a simple explanation. Certainly the two observers can measure different times, demonstrating that unlike Newtonian time, coordinate time is not invariant under transformations in relativity. Unfortunately in this case, the indications are that the proper time measured by observer 2 is less than than coordinate time measured by observer 1, not more.

The light clock thought experiment provided by Einstein, (where a photon bounces between two comoving mirrors) is the simplest demonstration of time not being invariant in relativity. It does not require knowledge of length contraction or gravitational time dilation to be taken into account.